# Message list: order by and group by query on cakephp and mysql

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I want to change my message list page/inbox. Currently it shows all the messages from the DB like if someone send me a message 3 times, it will all appear in my inbox. Now i want to make it simple like every sender will appear only once in the list and will show the latest message that he/she sent.

This is my code in cakephp:

```
$this->paginate = array(
  'Message'=> array(
    'conditions'=>array('Message.recipient_id'=>$this->user_id),
    'group' => array('Message.sender_id'),
    'order'=>'message_sent_date DESC',
    'limit'=> 20,
  )
);
```

The problem with this code is it shows the oldest message content. I think it's because group by always first before order by.

I was able to do it on mysql query but i don't know how to make it on cakephp.
Here's my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
SELECT *
FROM messages WHERE recipient_id = 114
ORDER BY message_viewed_date DESC
) AS messages 
GROUP BY sender_id
ORDER BY message_viewed_date DESC
```

Please help me with this.. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a question suitable for StackOverflow.  Please show what you've tried, what problem(s) you're having...etc.  Not just "please do this for me".

Comment: I've edited the question sir and already have an answer, i solved it by myself. I want to post the answer here but i cannot because it still on hold.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - I've nominated for reopen.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (make sure your models are set up correctly):

```
$results = $this->Message->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'recipient_id' => 114
    ),
    'group' => 'sender_id',
    'order' => 'message_viewed_date DESC'
));
```

No need for the sub query there, it's not doing anything fancy. [The manual will help you with queries like this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html).

Comment: But i need the sub query because it will make the message list show the latest message content every sender.

Comment: if i use this code it will show the oldest message content for every sender.

Answer (score 0):

I've solve this problem using the Model::query() http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query

here's my code:

```
$messages = $this->Message->query("SELECT id FROM(SELECT * FROM messages WHERE recepient_id = ". $this->user_id ." ORDER BY message_sent_date DESC) AS Message GROUP BY sender_id ORDER BY message_sent_date DESC");    
for($i=0; $i<count($messages); $i++){
$message_id[$i] = $messages[$i]['Message']['id'];
}
$this->paginate = array(
    'Message'=> array(
      'conditions'=>array('Message.id' => $message_id, 'Message.recepient_id'=>$this->user_id, 'Message.hidden_on_to'=>false),
      'limit'=>20,
      'order'=>array('Message.message_sent_date' => 'DESC'),
      'recursive'=>0,
      'fields'=>array('Message.id', 'Message.message_content', 'Message.message_sent_date', 'Message.message_viewed_date', 'Sender.id', 'Sender.username')
    )
);
```